# Post Picture with Feed dialog on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I would like, in my app, to share a picture on my wall to show to all my friends. (Like if I was posting a photo on facebook).

I'm trying to use the feed dialog but I think i'm doing it wrong.

```
    FB.ui({
         method:    'feed'
        ,name:      'Look at my picture !'
        ,link:      'https://www.facebook.com/link_to_app'
        ,caption:   "Application title"
        ,source: "http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/funny-pictures-kitten-finished-his-milk-and-wants-a-cookie.jpg" 

    }
```

So how can I publish a picture on my wall?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the line starting with `,source` instead add the line

```
,picture: ......,  //url of picture in place of the .....
```